# CakePHP Logs Only Displaying Cloudflare IPs

Tags: php, cakephp, ip, cloudflare

I am very confused, so please bear with me on this one.

I have a CakePHP web application (v3.8) and for some reason, it does not have a /http/ folder...I didn't develop the base part of the app, and for reasons I can't go into, I can't contact the developer.

This usually does not matter since the site works great!  My issue is that we run IP logging so users can see IPs that have logged into their accounts.  We started using Cloudflare, and now we are logging Cloudflare's IPs instead of actual user IPs.  My research brought me to [this page](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.Http.ServerRequest.html#$trustProxy), but the file referenced that I need to change does not exist.  The file that needs to be changed is [/http/serverrequest.php](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/source-class-Cake.Http.ServerRequest.html#33-2515), and the file does not exist.

Any help would be appreciated, I am a bit over my head with this one, but it seems like if I can find (or create) that file, and set the proxy setting to true, the IP logs will work.  My main concern is if I am missing something and that isn't a good solution for whatever reason, which is why I am asking for help!  Thanks again in advance!

Comment: Note that you're not supposed to modify that file, but what exactly do you mean by "_it does not have a /http/ folder_"? Where exactly did you look for it?

Comment: Besides, have you looked at fixing this at server level? https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029696071

Comment: @ndm the folder does not exist at all on the server, but I was specifically looking for it in the root directory.  I have tried to fix it at a server level, that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Did you search case insensitively, because the folder is named `Http`? It should be located in composers vendor folder, `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http`.

Comment: You don't need to change any file in Cake to do this. You need to look at the [provided interface](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/request-response.html#trusting-proxy-headers) for setting this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ndm's comment, I found the file in /vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http and was able to make the changes there.